Flutter error in Ffmpeg, "Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: No such file or directory" in macOS desktop version
I'm trying video trim video using ffmpeg, for macOS desktop application.
I have downloaded ffmpeg from here for macOS.
Here is my code
    String mainPath = 'Users/apple/Workspace/User/2024/Project/videoapp/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/';
        mainPath = mainPath.substring(0, mainPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
    
                  Directory directoryExe3 = Directory("$mainPath");
                  var dbPath = path.join(directoryExe3.path,
                      "App.framework/Resources/flutter_assets/assets/ffmpeg/ffmpegmacos");
//here in "Products/Debug/" folder desktop app will generate

//directoryExe3 path will be, Users/apple/Workspace/User/2024/Project/videoapp/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug

//and dbPath will be, Users/apple/Workspace/User/2024/Project/videoapp/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/App.framework/Resources/flutter_assets/assets/ffmpeg/ffmpegmacos

//so when app will run it can access it from this path

//executable code, command for ffmpeg

String transpose_str += "crop=" +
              out_w.toInt().toString() +
              ":" +
              out_h.toInt().toString() +
              ":" +
              x!.toInt().toString() +
              ":" +
              y!.toInt().toString() +
              ",";
          transpose_str += "scale=960:192";

Future<ProcessResult> result_ = Process.run(dbPath, [
                "-ss",
                timestamp,
                "-i",
                inputFilePath,
                "-t",
                endTime,
                "-vf",
                transpose_str,
                "-an",
                "./temp.mp4",
              ]); 

Now when I run this in macOS desktop verison, it gives me error at Process.run that in dbPath, Unhandled Exception: ProcessException: No such file or directory.
Any help would be appreciate!
when i run this as desktop version it should get file from assets.
